# check if pinch is released in UIPinchGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

How do I check if a pinch has been released? I tried

```
- (IBAction)resizeImage:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
   if (sender.delaysTouchesEnded)
   //here
}
```

and it didn't work out

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to check for `sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` and possibly `sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled`

Answer (score 2):

UIAdam's answer worked for me...

```
    if([(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {

    }
```

This is my complete method with zoom (CGAffineTransformScale)

(self.pictureCard01 is a UIView subclass which I'm pinching)

```
   - (IBAction)PinchGesture01:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {
                CGFloat factor = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)sender scale];
                if (factor > 2) {
                    factor = 2;
                }
                else if (factor < 1) {
                    factor = 1;
                }

                [UIView animateWithDuration:2 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent
                animations:^{
                    self.pictureCard01.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, factor, factor);
                }
                completion:nil];

                if([(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
                {
                    [self performSelector:@selector(resize:) withObject:self.pictureCard01 afterDelay:2];
                }
            }

      -(void)resize:(UIView*)myview{

                    [UIView animateWithDuration:2 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent
                                     animations:^{
                                         myview.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1, 1);
                                     }
                                     completion:nil];
                }
```